# How to Capture text for multiple divs with same data attribute?

Tags: javascript

Multiple divs contains same html5 data attribute

with same values. Inside each divs are b and p tags with same html 5 data attributes and same values.

requirement is to capture each div values in this format. < b tag text p tag text |  b2 tag text p2 tag text | b3 tag text p3 tag text >  and so on. Example  result---
 T1 title1  D1 description1 |  T2 title2  D2 description2 |  T3 title3  D3 description3

Here is the div code

```
<div data-v-46636d4a="" class="panel_2N_jF">
  <div data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="selected-prescription">
    <b data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="prescription-name">T1 title1</b>
    <p data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="prescription-description">D1 description1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="selected-prescription">
    <b data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="prescription-name">T2 title 2</b>
    <p data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="prescription-description">D2 description2</p>
  </div>
  <div data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="selected-prescription">
    <b data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="prescription-name">T3 title3</b>
    <p data-v-46636d4a="" data-purpose="prescription-description">D3 description3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used simple  this code:

```
console.log(
  document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > b").textContent + ' ' 
+ document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > p").textContent + ' ' + '|' 
+ document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > b").textContent + ' ' 
+ document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > p").textContent + ' ' + '|' 
+ document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > b").textContent + ' ' 
+ document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > p").textContent
);
```

But what is the ideal way to do this for multiple divs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on MDN. It returns a `NodeList` of elements, which you can then turn into an array and iterate over (either with `Array.from` or the spread operator, i.e. `new Array(...nodeList)`.

It looks like your data is like this:

```
<body>
  <div data-my-attr="value">
    <b>Tag Text 1</b>
    <p>Paragraph text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-my-attr="value">
    <b>Tag Text 2</b>
    <p>Paragraph text 2</p>
  </div>
  ... <!-- more divs -->
</body>
```

And the output you want is: `Tag Text 1 Paragraph text 1 | Tag Text 2 Paragraph Text 2`.

You can get all the divs with a given data attribute by using this function call:

`const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-my-attr]')`.
Then iterate over them:

```
const texts = [...divs].map(div => {
  return `${div.querySelector('b').textContent} ${div.querySelector('p').textContent`
})
const result = texts.join('|')
```

Comment: Hi Nathan Could you pls use JavaScript as you have used advanced es6 so my system doesn’t support it. Or pls transpile the code and post it here

Comment: You should be able to change `const` to `var`, `[...divs]` to `Array.from(divs)`, and the template to string concatenation `value + ' ' + value`. If you don't have access to `Array.from` or `Array.join` in your environment for some reason, you should be able to google for some polyfills or libraries you can use to get the same output.

For example, the MDN page on Array.from has a polyfill for older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you

```js
var Div_Childs = document.querySelector('div[data-v-46636d4a]').children;

var message = [];

for( var i = 0; i < Div_Childs.length; i++ ) {
  message.push(  Div_Childs[i].querySelector('b').textContent + ' '
                + Div_Childs[i].querySelector('p').textContent );
}

console.log (message.join(' | '));
```

```html
<div data-v-46636d4a class="panel_2N_jF">
  <div data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="selected-prescription">
    <b data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="prescription-name">T1 title1</b>
    <p data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="prescription-description">D1 description1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="selected-prescription">
    <b data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="prescription-name">T2 title 2</b>
    <p data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="prescription-description">D2 description2</p>
  </div>
  <div data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="selected-prescription">
    <b data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="prescription-name">T3 title3</b>
    <p data-v-46636d4a data-purpose="prescription-description">D3 description3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

?